# The order of script execution and layout?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Script execution will block html parsing, so Layout should be placed after script execution.Why is the Layout in front of the performance panel?
[image]

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <h1>world</h1>
  </body>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</html>
```

index.js

`console.log("hello world!");`

index.css

`* {padding: 0;margin: 0;}`

And then click

[image]

Comment: Not an answer but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for `<link>`

Comment: Chrome may use a different *yielding* algorithm when showing a file:// page in some cases. Use a localhost server instead.